# Development of smartTV applications for Sony

Tags: sony, smart-tv

Tell me, please:

1. For what platform at this moment need to develop *smart-TV applications* for  **Sony and Panasonic TV 2012, 2013, 2014 and 2015**?
2. How to get approve for applications for all of this platforms?

Comment: I suggest you add a tag 'Sony',  they have a developer support team who will answer questions with 'Sony' tag on SO.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know Panasonic.
I had looked into Sony's, coz I have a Sony smart TV.

You could get useful information from the Sony Developer World -https://developer.sony.com/develop/tvs/

To answer your question, for Sony

**1** Sony has a table on the above page:

> **Supported platforms**
>
> The following table shows which platforms are
>   supported by our TVs and home entertainment products. See the pages
>   for the individual platforms for more information on how to develop
>   apps for them.
>   [image]

**2** You have to contact sony

https://developer.sony.com/develop/tvs/app-promotion/
https://partner.developer.sony.com/contact/
You can submit an app if you're an registered developer
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I see  all of you write.
Firstly, no information on the requirements for applications on different platforms.
Secondly, when we try to put the application in approve, get on:
https://android.developer.sony.com/pages/account/signin/?redir=/pages/application/submit/branch/

No understanding of how to send in approve any application other than Android (with Android any thing clear) for Sony.

Comment: 1) What do you mean by requirements? You asked platforms, I answered platforms with that table from Sony.  2) Sony says you need to 'email' or 'submit'. So I am guessing other than Android you have to ask them which means 'email'...

Answer (score 0):

For Panasonic you have to register here - http://developer.vieraconnect.com/ 
After the registration you gonna have a new section in Control Pannel - Submit Apps.

Panasonic Team has quite a strict rules for app documentation, so better to follow their example.